# Creating a checkbox java list

Tags: java, swing, highlight, checkboxlist

i am trying to generate a checkbox list feeded by some records from a database just like the image (JAVA Swing), initially i tried with several chexkboxes but it didn't work, now i am trying with a multiple selection list but it didn't work as well and none of the answered questions here looks like to solve the specific needs i have.

Specifications:

- Multiple selection list.
- Every node of the list must have a checkbox object.
- When checked every node must stay highlighted.
- It must have an scrollbar if the content is bigger to the initially setted dimentions.

Comment: Why do you need checkboxes in your list? A checkbox only supports 2 states (checked and unchecked). So does an element in a multiple selection list. Just hold Crtl-pressed, when selecting more than one element from the list.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno: It's easier for a user to check a bunch of boxes than to hold down the Ctrl key for several pages.

Comment: Why not a one-column `JTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It must have an scrollbar if the content is bigger to the initially set dimensions.

Put the `JList` inside a `JScrollPane`.

> When checked every node must stay highlighted.

This is going to confuse the user.  The check marks are sufficient.

> Every node of the list must have a check box object.

You'll have to extend a `JList` and a `ListCellRenderer` to gain this functionality.  The `ListSelectionListener` that I have is over 100 lines of code.

You might find an already existing check box `JList` on the web.  I have one in a book.